# Keep Hidden Table Column/Cells Visible Using Session Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, checkbox

I have a table where I can check a checkbox and it will log all of the contents in the row. Once you check a checkbox, another column (Quantity #) appears with a textbox/spinner inside the cell. If it is unchecked, then the corresponding textbox/spinner disappears.

I want to use session storage to be able to keep any cells in the Quantity # column visible if the row is checked throughout refreshes until the page is closed. I was able to use session storage to keep the checkboxes checked, but am having a problem with getting the Quantity # column to remain visible so long as the checkbox is checked for that row.

How can I do this?

I have included the HTML for the checkbox row and the JavaScript that keeps the checkboxes checked so it can be used to base an answer off of if needed.

HTML for the checkbox and the appearing table cell:

```
<td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
<td class="quantity_num ui-widget-content" name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
```

JavaScript for the session storage for the checkbox and for the spinner in the appearing table cell:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
    });

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        // save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
        // using the checkbox "id" attribute
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
    });
});


$(function () {
    $(".check").change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
    console.log($('input.check').is(':checked'));
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');
        console.log(quantity);

  if($('input.check').is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(true);
    else
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(false);



    $(this).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({
      spin: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.value > quantity ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", quantity );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value <= 1 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 1 );
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  });
```

EDIT:
HTML/PHP for table:

```
<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]" class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][sku]" class="sku ui-widget-content" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][special-id]" class="special-id ui-widget-content" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][description]" class="description ui-widget-content" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quantity]" class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][unit]" class="unit ui-widget-content" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use show() hide()? if a checkbox is checked?

Comment: I am using something similar to that in that whenever I check a checkbox, the column appears...however, on refresh for example, the checkbox remains checked and the column then disappears

Comment: if you have something to show and hide, then try to trigger it on page load, like call all checkbox to check if they are checked, then show etc

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to go about this...would you be able to post some sort of outline at least so I could see it visually?

Comment: post your rendered HTML for those checkboxs, I could try

Comment: I edited my post with the HTML/PHP code of my table with the checkboxes